# React native drag and drop

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I'm trying to implement drag and drop in a React Native application.

Has anyone out there used [this](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-drag-drop) ? Somehow I'm not able to drag the text. There are not enough steps to use the npm module.

After debugging for some time I found that onLayout & onLongPress are undefined, can anyone help me on this ?

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you're new to React Native (as am I, kind of), and you don't have an example of your code, there might be a few things going on. *(and there is a high chance you already know all of these things)*.

Did you follow [this](https://github.com/kriskelly/react-native-drag-drop/blob/master/examples/BasicExample/index.ios.js) example? Here they set `onLayout` and `onLongPress` as the props of the `DraggableThing` component. Next they call the component with functions (`onDragItemLayout, startDragHandler`) bound to these properties. These functions are supplied by importing the createDropZone, did you import everything?

If you did, importing third-party components is kind of a hassle, because most of the times you're required to do some things in xCode. Not sure if that's also the case right now, but it might be something to look into.

Also my advice would be to take a look at the module supplied in the answer above.

Comment: I have followed all the things you have mentioned , may be I need to check in xCode, because importing was done by npm itself.

Comment: Hmm, maybe add the .xcodeproj file to your `/Libraries` folder, and add the `.a` file found in `/Products` to 'Link Binaries with Libraries' in your Build phases tab, visible when you click on your project file. Here is an example: https://www.smashingmagazine.com/2016/04/how-to-build-your-first-ios-app-with-javascript/ , search for 'Build Phases' and it should be that paragraph.

Answer (score 0):

This is a simple React drag and drop.

```js
class Square extends React.Component {
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = {
      posx: 10,
      posy: 10,
    };
    this.setDrag = this.setDrag.bind(this);
    this.startDrag = this.startDrag.bind(this);
    this.stopDrag = this.stopDrag.bind(this);
  }
  
  componentDidMount() {
    this.sq.addEventListener('mousedown', this.setDrag);
  }
  
  startDrag(e) {
    this.setState({
      posx: parseInt(e.clientX - this.startPosX, 10),
      posy: parseInt(e.clientY - this.startPosY, 10),
    });
    this.startPosX = e.clientX - this.state.posx;
    this.startPosY = e.clientY - this.state.posy;
  }
  
  stopDrag() {
    document.documentElement.removeEventListener('mousemove', this.startDrag);
    document.documentElement.removeEventListener('mouseup', this.stopDrag);
    this.sq.addEventListener('mousedown', this.setDrag);
  }
  
  setDrag(e) {
    this.sq.removeEventListener('mousedown', this.setDrag);
    this.startPosX = e.clientX - this.state.posx;
    this.startPosY = e.clientY - this.state.posy;
    document.documentElement.addEventListener('mousemove', this.startDrag);
    document.documentElement.addEventListener('mouseup', this.stopDrag);
  }
  
  render() {
    return (
      <div
        className='square'
        style={{
          left: this.state.posx,
          top: this.state.posy,
        }}
        ref={(sq) => { this.sq = sq; }}
      >
        {this.state.posx}
      </div>
    );
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(
  <Square />,
  document.getElementById('app')
);
```

```css
.square {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background: #900;
  border: 1px solid #333;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<div id="app"></div>
```